# Extensible Markdown-like Module In Perl?

Tags: html, perl, markdown, perl-module, dancer

I'm building a `Dancer` application in perl.

My app listens for POST events, stores them in a database, does some calculations and then potentially POSTs to another http endpoint (which renders events in text/html); In the module I use to make the updates, I use HTML formatting like:

```
$helper->post_update({
    text => 'some text that is escaped',
    main_text => 'unescaped text, <i>with html</i>',
    ...
});
```

Is there a perl module out there that allows me to have extensible, markdown-like support?

eg:

replace

`$newtext = "<b>this is bold</b> <i>this is italic</i> <span class="something">@evalutated_with_a_custom_rule</span> ... etc";`

with

`$newtext = Markdown::Module->run_rules("*this is bold* _this is italic_ @evalutated_with_a_custom_rule ... etc");`

... in order to further de-couple my model and view.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there are plenty of ways that you could do this such as:

1. Using [Template::Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/module/Template%3a%3aToolkit) to replace your text with main_text being fed from a markdown template file.
2. Using [Text::Markdown](https://metacpan.org/module/Text%3a%3aMarkdown) to convert your resultant markdown with HTML which you can then serve back to the client.

Comment: I've used Template::Toolkit before for rendering html; typically you pass variables to a template, but that's not really what I want in this case... I'll take a look at Text::Markdown - can you explain how you think Template::Toolkit would apply here?

Comment: My thought that was you would develop your template text in Markdown with tags in the Markdown template ready to be replaced with the posted data during processing.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [WikiText module](https://metacpan.org/pod/WikiText) and its submodules. E.g.

```
use WikiText::Socialtext;
my $wikitext = '*this is bold* _this is italic_ @evalutated_with_a_custom_rule ... etc';
my $html = WikiText::Socialtext->new($wikitext)->to_html;
```

… would produce:

```
<p><strong>this is bold</strong> <em>this is italic</em> @evalutated_with_a_custom_rule</p>
```

BTW, if the `@` in front of `evaluated_with_a_custom_role` is meant to be markup, you will have to escape it with a preceding backslash or use single quotes.  In a double quoted string perl is going to interpolate the contents of the array `@evalutated_with_a_custom_rule`.

Comment: I will give this a try; please fix the "`" in your last paragraph as well (for correct quoting).